# Why did Adobe Flash store integers bitshifted by three bits to the right?

Tags: flash, internals

This is more  curiosity than an actual problem but I feel like this belongs here.

My question is: why did Adobe Flash Player store integers in memory shifted by three bits (times eight) from a byte-aligned perspective?

As can bee seen in the following example (30 seconds):

https://i.imgur.com/DlZYLFx.mp4

There is no explanation about this in the [SWF format specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) (specifically chapter Integer types and byte order).

Comment: Are you sure this is generally the case? Maybe it's just how this game's developers chose to store the number.

Comment: @a3f You mean the developers of all flash games have standarized that they all store the values times eight? :) Sounds impossible. It's not only this game. Also see: http://cheatengine.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=451442&sid=73fb231bbf76b37139aaa71dd0a741a7

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't know, that why I am asking :)

Comment: Not exactly the same title, but the accepted answer addresses the question here.

Comment: Ah so the 3 bits are used to describe the type! Good to know. Thanks for the other question/answer.